# Is this amount of wobble in my newel post acceptable?

Tags: wood, stairs, carpentry, post

I just had some new newel posts and railing installed.

I’m on the fence whether or not the amount of wobble is acceptable. My wife believes it is too much to accept but I’m not really sure what’s practical or normal.

https://imgur.com/a/fVTGqFz

In the video I’m putting a little effort into moving it. Definitely not excessive though.

I would be fine leaning on this but a full force stumble with my 200 lbs. I’m not sure.

What do you guys think, normal or too much wiggle?

Comment: That isn't the finished railing, is it?

Comment: To clarify, spindles are being installed on a second trip. 

I asked to split the trips so I had time to fix the walls and stain the wood prior to the spindles being installed.

Comment: Your question is a matter of opinion, so it's off topic. If you'd like to ask how to fix it, please provide more detail. My opinion is that this is completely unacceptable. Obviously your carpenter's opinion is different.

Comment: You could modify the question to - "Following excellent but reasonable construction practices, how much deflection should a 30 inch newel post display when subjected to a 150 lb side load before installation of balusters? "   You might get some answers from people with experience doing this.   [Here](https://www.lerchbates.com/news/deflections-in-deck-and-balcony-railings/) is some material on what is *allowed*, and the article notes that whatever standards exist for stiffness (not strength) would allow perhaps 3 inches of deflection, that nobody would find acceptable.

Comment: While the question asks for opinion, there does seem to be a code-based answer for it. A simple [edit] to ask for the relevant code requirements would make this completely on topic.

Comment: Note that it will wobble a lot less after it is finished.  For instance when I installed a kitset years ago, it came with half a newel to go against the wall and to support the ballustrade there.  While it may end up still bad, I think you are jumping the gun here, and possibly weakening it before it has been fastened properly.

Answer (score 5):

Code requires the assembly to handle a 200 lb side load.

It looks like the installer needs to finish, so when he does show back up to do so, if possible, before he finishes, explain your doubt, and ask him if you leaned up against it will it hold, and do so while he is there. If he balks at the idea, HE has a problem and needs to correct it.